# Using Node to access FTP in another server

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, ftp, fs

I need to access FTP in another server *(Ubuntu)*.

My Node.js API receive an image from user, and then needs to upload it to another server using FTP connection. However, if user folder doesn't exist, I need to create folder before sending the image.

How can i do this?

I'm using express-upload to get files:

```
const express       = require('express');
const upload        = require('express-fileupload');

const app = express();

app.use(upload());

app.use('/upload', async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.files.image);
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Basic FTP](https://www.npmjs.com/package/basic-ftp), an FTP client module, and use its `ensureDir()` method to implement the requirement "if user folder doesn't exists, I need to create folder before sending image".

According to its document:

> ...we make sure a remote path exists, creating all directories as necessary.
>
> `await client.ensureDir("my/remote/directory")`

Then, you can send the image using its `upload()` method.

Comment: This method upload() just enable expres to get files like that: `req.files.image`
Image its a variable name to front sending into post.

You can get name of image `req.files.image.name` or or buffer(for FTP) and others.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload